# Can I split up my Capistrano capfile?

Tags: capistrano

I've got a capfile that has a role defined at the top of it, with a bunch of tasks below.  It works great, but I want to be able to easily (and programatically) update the machines in the roles list.  I know I could do it in place, but to be safe, I'd like to be able to split out my capfile into (essentially) two files: hosts and tasks

Currently (generically):

```
role :machines,
"machine1",
"machine2"

desc "This is task 1"
task :task1 do
  # stuff
end
```

I'd like to be able to have something like the following (ignore the "syntax"):

```
role :machines ==> {Get this information from 'hosts.cap' or something}

desc "This is task 1"
task :task1 do
  # stuff
end
```

Is there a way to break the capfile up?  Or would I need to dive into source to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The vanilla `Capfile` used to ship with the line `load 'config/deploy'` - maybe you can leverage that to load multiple files.

Answer (score 1):

Since a Capfile is just Ruby, you can use Ruby code to do what you want. For example, if your hosts.cap file looked like this:

```
db-master.example.com
db-slave1.example.com
```

you would get it in an array with this Ruby code:

```
File.read('hosts.cap').strip.split
```

and to give it to the `role` call properly, use the splat (*) operator:

```
role :db_hosts, *File.read('hosts.cap').strip.split
```

although I would recommend to put it in two parts, because it is clearer:

```
machines = File.read('hosts.cap').strip.split
role :db_hosts, *machines
```